# I'd like for my streams in RxJS to wait for all items in the stream to complete before moving on, but cant figure out how

Tags: neo4j, rxjs, nestjs

I'm using RxJS in combination with Neo4J and NestJS.

Every step needs to be fully completed in order for the next step to be able to process successfully, so ideally i'd like to replicate a Promise.all() for each of the following steps found in the chunk of code below.
Problem is, that `tap` doesnt seem to allow me to wait for all promises to complete, and I'm really not sure how to achive this.

```js
loadBooks() {
    const booksObservable =
      this.booksService.getBooksFromAPI();

      booksObservable
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((response) => response.data),
        tap((protocol) => {
          return from(
            this.booksService.find(book.name).then((bookNode) => {
              if (!bookNode) {
                return from(
                  this.bookService.create({
                    name: book.name
                  }),
                );
              }
            }),
          );
        }),
        groupBy((book) => book.category),
        tap((categoryName) => {
          return from(
            this.bookCategoryService
              .find(categoryName.key)
              .then((categoryNode) => {
                if (!categoryNode) {
                  return from(
                    this.bookCategoryService.create({
                      name: categoryName.key,
                    }),
                  );
                }
              }),
          );
        }),
        mergeMap((group) => group),
        tap((book) => {
          let bookId: string;
          let categoryId: string;
          return from(
            this.bookService
              .find(book.name)
              .then(async (bookNode) => {
                if (!bookNode) {
                  throw new NotFoundError(
                    `Could not find book by name ${book.name}`,
                  );
                }
                bookId = bookNode.getId();
                await this.bookCategoryService
                  .find(book.category)
                  .then(async (categoryNode) => {
                    if (!categoryNode) {
                      throw new NotFoundError(
                        `Could not find category by name ${protocol.category}`,
                      );
                    }
                    categoryId = categoryNode.getId();
                    await this.bookService.relateToCategory(
                      bookId,
                      categoryId,
                    );
                  });
              }),
          );
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        return 'done';
      });
```

How do i make it so that the operations in the tap fully complete for each and every item in the stream, before moving on tho the next function in the pipe?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to substitute `tap` with `concatMap`. I would also advice to use Observables only rather than mixing Observables and Promises. What type is returned by `this.bookCategoryService.find`? Can you change `this.bookCategoryService.find` to return an Observable?

Comment: From the perspective of RxJS, tap is a null operation. It doesn't DO anything. You can perform a side effect, but anything you return will be ignored. I've skimmed your code, but I can't really make out the semantics of what you're trying to accomplish. The names you've given some operations are a hint, but it's not enough to help guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Picci, using concatMap indeed did the trick.

Comment: Also thanks @MrkSef, i hadn't considered that tap is a noop. That's quite insightful.

Comment: This is my first time using rxjs, so pardon me @MrkSef if the code isnt very idiomatic, or expressive. The gist of it is that i have three operations i need to complete: first i create books, then i create their genres, and then i create a relation between the two items, but the last process depends on the first two being complete.

Comment: I also have another snippet of code where i use forkJoin to combine the two observables for the first two processes, and perform the last task once that completes. Oddly enough, that code runs ±5x faster...

Comment: You got it to work with concatMap as @Picci suggested? You can answer your own question below so that the next guy with a similar problem can benefit (also, I'd love to see it)    :)